# Posting excel data into Access as a record

Tags: excel, finance, vba

I have a "budget worksheet" I am building for my company. The purpose of the worksheet is so all line managers/supervisors use the same template and can post their expenses (budget) individually to my pre-made Access database to form one large consolidated budget for our whole business.

The budget worksheet is already made and is working very well. All of the expenses are consolidated into a "database" tab in my worksheet and formatted exactly how my Access database is set up. Right now I can build a budget, and MANUALLY copy/paste the data right into my Access table without any errors.

I would like to improve on this by making it so I can just click a "Post Budget" button in Excel and all of the data is posted to my Access database without having line managers/supervisors entering Access at all.

Anyone know how I would go about doing this? I've worked with linking Excel/Access before, but only to retrieve Access data into Excel - not vice-versa.

Thank you!!

Comment: In VBA it's not too hard - you can make a Connection (Probably using the JET engine if it's on the fileserver), create an ADODB Recordset of the table, use the Recordset's `.AddNew` method, set all the required `.Fields` equal to your budget's values (Have it pull from the worksheet if you want, it may be better to have them enter the data on a Userform) , then `.Update` to post the data.  100% doable, not too hard - the book "VBA and Macros: Microsoft Excel 2010" has a great example of a store inventory system doing just this.  (Using DAO instead of ADODB, almost identical)

Comment: Hmm, think you could give me a coded example? Let's say I have one column ("ID") and 1 record ("0001") that I want to post to a table called tblAccess in my database file "database.accdb". How would I establish the connection and post the record?

Comment: Sure, added an answer below.  (It's using the ACE engine instead of JET, I guess JET is dated)

Answer (score 0):

I made a Macro Enabled Workbook called MyTestWorkbook.xlsm and saved it.  I went to the VBA editor (Alt+F11), and went to Insert>Module , and it created Module1.  Now you will need to go to Tools>References and Check/Enable "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library", this gives it access to the ADO library and it will not run without this.

So the target database is called Database.accdb and it's located in C:\ . It has one table, tblAccess, with one column, ID.  In my workbook I have a number in cell A1.  So here's the code that goes in Module1.---

```
Sub TestACEConnection()

    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

    cnn.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\Database.accdb"
    cnn.Open

    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    rst.Open "tblAccess", cnn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

    Dim myValue As Integer
    myValue = Range("A1").Value

    rst.AddNew
    rst.Fields("ID") = myValue
    rst.Update

    rst.Close
    cnn.Close

End Sub
```

Some considerations going forward , referring to a cell just by "Range" and not specifying the worksheet, workbook, and excel instance can cause problems , but I ignored that to keep it clean.  The lock type specified on the `rst.open` line is important, I honestly don't understand it as well as I should - but you can open recordsets as read-only, or lock records that you're reading from, so getting a good understanding of what lock type to use will help.  And I really recommend doing the input from a userform, but that's just a personal preference.

Hope this helps -

Comment: I'm getting a "compile error: user-type not defined" on the second line that highlights "cnn As ADODB.Connection"

Comment: @mcrackin My guess is you missed this part `you will need to go to Tools>References and Check/Enable "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library", this gives it access to the ADO library and it will not run without this.`